# How do I sort my call logs to get only calls made in a specific month?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Please I need guidance on the issue CallLogs
I am trying to sort the managedQuery to only list calls made in a specific month.
The code I used is given below but I still get errors

```
Cursor Log_query=this.managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, call_logs, String.valueOf(Calendar.MONTH), null, null);
```

please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?